# getting a sum value of innerjoined and union all tables and use it in other query

Tags: mysql, sql

please help, this is so very difficult for me but i know that someone out there  can solve this problem.

so this is it:

first i will just get the value of the 2 tables that was unioned all and innerjoined them in another 2 tables. so i have this code:

```
SELECT VSI.customer, IFNULL(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0),0) AS Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE 'VIC ENTERPRISES' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE 'VIC ENTERPRISES' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO
```

so the result of that code is just like this:

[image]

now the second one is: i would just like to add or sum, all the results in amount column.

so my code is just like this:

```
SELECT VSI.customer, IFNULL(SUM(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) AS Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE 'VIC ENTERPRISES' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE 'VIC ENTERPRISES' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO
```

and the result is:

[image]

so now that i have it, there is no problem if it was just only the result of a one year. my problem is i would just like to get 5 results of amounts in a particular or specific customer in 5 years.
 to elaborate more:

since i already the total amounts of the year 2017 that i was given as an example.
and the name of the customer is the VIC ENTERPRISE. so i would just like to get the another total result of the amount in year (example: 2016,2015,2014 and 2013) and in every year there is a total amount just like this:

[image]

that's the result that i want to get. so if i will not enter or select a customer name , it will display all the amounts in a specific year of all specific customer.
 i want to display it just like this:
[image]

the problem for that is, the query get only one result of a one customer. so all of the result of the amounts in every year are just the same.

this is my current code that i used that have a problem:

```
SELECT cust.customername,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) AS Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO) AS Amount,'2017' AS year1,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) AS Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO) AS Amount2,'2016' AS year4,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) AS Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO) AS Amount3,'2015' AS year3,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) AS Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO) AS Amount4,'2014' AS year4,
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) AS Amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE '%' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO) AS Amount5,'2013' AS year4
        FROM 000_customer cust WHERE cust.customername LIKE '%'
```

Comment: mysql .. the sqlyog Ultimate.

Comment: There’s no way I’m trawling through all that. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You need CASE WHEN to the sum and create multiple columns fro each year. Like this

```
SUM(
   CASE WHEN 
       siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
   THEN IFNULL(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) 
   ELSE 0) as amount2017,
SUM(
   CASE WHEN 
       siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' 
   THEN IFNULL(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) 
   ELSE 0) as amount2016,
```

So if date comes into 2017 year you add the amount else 0 and the same fo 2016. Like this

```
SELECT VSI.customer, 
    SUM(
       CASE WHEN 
           siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
       THEN IFNULL(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) 
       ELSE 0) as amount2017,
    SUM(
       CASE WHEN 
           siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31' 
       THEN IFNULL(vSI.Amount + IFNULL(act.FREIGHT, 0)),0) 
       ELSE 0) as amount2016
...
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REFERENCENO, CUSTOMER, SIDATE AS TransDate, SALESTYPE, IFNULL(100_si.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) AS Amount
            FROM 100_si
            WHERE (REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND CUSTOMER LIKE 'VIC ENTERPRISES' AND SIDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT cm.REFERENCENO, siH.CUSTOMER, siH.SIDATE AS TransDate, siH.SALESTYPE, IFNULL(cm.TOTALAMOUNT, 0) * -1 AS Amount
            FROM 100_si siH INNER JOIN 100_credit_memo cm ON (siH.REFERENCENO = cm.REFERENCENO)
            WHERE (cm.REFERENCENO IS NOT NULL AND siH.CUSTOMER LIKE 'VIC ENTERPRISES' AND siH.SIDATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-30')
        ) vSI 
        INNER JOIN 000_customer cust ON (vSI.CUSTOMER = cust.CUSTOMERNAME)
        INNER JOIN 100_actual_transaction act ON vSI.REFERENCENO = act.REFERENCENO
```

Comment: i think it didn't solve my problem but thank you very much for your suggestion, i really appreciate it. the only reason here i think is the customer. because when you see the where clause it must be select the specific customer or each customer in that year for the total amount. because the amount there is correct but it is only one result of one customer not in each customer. i tried to use the where customer = cust.customername but i got an error. i wont accept the cust.customer

Comment: The answer updated - added example for 2016 and 2017

Comment: i'ved got an error. "Incorrect parameter count in the call function 'IFNULL'"